# MFC: CBitmapCreateCompatibleBitmap() gives different results based on two compatible CDC's passed to it?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi, cbitmap

Why would passing a compatible DC and the DC the compatible one is based on to `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` give different results?

This one creates a monochrome bitmap:

```
CDC dcMem; 
dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(mydc);
destBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dcMem, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
CBitmap* pBmpOld = dcMem.SelectObject (destBitmap);
// ... Draw on to the DC ....
dcMem.SelectObject (pBmpOld);
```

This one creates the correct color bitmap:

```
CDC dcMem; 
dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(mydc);
destBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap (mydc, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
CBitmap* pBmpOld = dcMem.SelectObject (destBitmap);
// ... Draw on to the DC ....
dcMem.SelectObject (pBmpOld);
```

TIA!!

Comment: See the remarks under [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap).

Comment: I remember the issue dxiv is pointing out biting me 20 years ago... A tip for doing win32/MFC development: the first, say, 5-10 times you use an API call, read the corresponding MSDN article from start to end. It may seem like this will take a  lot of time, and it will, but it will pay off - there are many implicit assumptions and contextual knowledge for pretty much every call. But the documentation is top notch and reading it often and knowing it well is key to being able to use the APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, have a look at the [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap) documentation:

> Note: When a memory device context is created, it initially has a **1-by-1 monochrome bitmap** selected into it. If this memory device context is used in `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, the bitmap that is created is a **monochrome bitmap**. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used to create the memory device context, as shown in the following code ...